# Areas not rendering

Tags: rendering

I can't seem to solve why certain elements aren't rendering as expected. Any thoughts welcome, I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure out what to search for.

[image]

[Tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/blender-hard-surface-modeling/lighting-the-scene) - This is LinkedIn paid content so don't know if it's readily available

[image: Blender Render]

Comment: Hi Stew, welcome to Blender SE. We love to help. But we can only help, if you provide necessary informations. Unfortunately you did just provide 2 images. Since you seem to be a beginner, i would recommend to edit your question and add the link to your tutorial and open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions to provide your blend file so we can check it out and can quickly help you. Thx.

Comment: Another possibility for you is to search here (or on google) for e.g. "did not render" -> there are many questions like this here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, much appreciated. Is it common for only certain objects not to render, like the wheels and mesh window here? I've done quite a few little bits in the past (a couple of years ago so a bit rusty), but not had this problem before.

The link to the tutorial is here (LinkedIn Tutorial, but it's an outdated version of blender);

https://www.linkedin.com/learning/blender-hard-surface-modeling/lighting-the-scene?autoplay=true&resume=false&u=2037588

Will see how I add the blender file now

Comment: @Chris — thanks for explaining how this works, I've added my file if that helps. Appreciate it.

Comment: It might be quite simple. You have your 'BASIC SHAPES' set to be hidden in the viewport, but you haven't cancelled their render (the little camera icon next to the eye in the outliner. They are occluding your other objects.

Comment: Robin, thanks for this, that was it! Really appreciate you taking a look. Thanks for helping!